# printf("%+f", ..) still shows negative number

Tags: java, printf

I have a constant that's negative and I want the output to come out as positive. When I add a %+f it doesn't do anything and the output still comes out -15,123.45?

```
public static final double n2 = -15123.456789;

System.out.printf("%+,.2f\n", n2);
```

Comment: `System.out.printf("%+,.2f\n", -n2);`

Comment: Math.abs() is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

The format string `"%+,.2f\n"` only defines the formatting in which value must be printed. **It doesn't change the actual value.** If your input value is negative, the output string will display it as negative. It's like, when you make **something** bold, it doesn't change to **another thing**.

To convert the value to the opposite sign (- to +, + to -), you can multiply the value by `-1`: *Thanks to [kjbartel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28666057#comment45626887_28666057) for the shortcut.*

```
System.out.printf("%+,.2f\n", -1 * n2);
// or
System.out.printf("%+,.2f\n", -n2);
```

To convert the value to always be positive (- to +, + to +), you can use `Math.abs`: *Thanks to [zubergu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28666057#comment45626972_28666057) for the tip.*

```
System.out.printf("%+,.2f\n", Math.abs(n2));
```